# Can I break this function into two?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that contains something similar to the following. I can have one or more modals open on the screen at one time. Here's a **short** version of the code. In the real application there's a lot more so I would like to split this function into two:

```
function openModal(oLink, content) {
    var btns = {
        'Close': function (win) {
            modal.closeModal()
        }
    }
    var modal = $.modal({
        buttons: btns
    });
}
```

Is it possible for me to split this into two functions like this:

```
function btnsModal() {
    var btns = {
        'Close': function (win) {
            modal.closeModal()
        }
    }
    return btns;
}

function openModal(oLink, content) {
    var btn = btnsModal();
    var modal = $.modal({
        buttons: btn
    });
}
```

When I try this I get the error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'closeModal'
```

Does the first script only work because modal is defined in the same file as where modal.closeModal() is used?

Comment: if its working than yes else not first check this out

Comment: yes[.](http://www.space.space)

Comment: No, the first one works because both, the buttons object and the modal thingy are in the same scope (in the same function). It does not have to do anything with files. Or did you mean "function"? In that  case: yes.

Comment: Do you want a default behavior in every modal?

Comment: It's not working :-(  I mention at the end of my question that I get an error message. @david - Yes I do want this default behavior in every model.

Comment: What does `win` refer to inside the event handler? Could you do `win.closeModal()`? It would be easier if we knew which library you are using. I recommend to have a look at the API documentation, I'm sure there is an easy to refer to the modal instance from inside the event handler.

Comment: $.modal is part of what library?

Comment: What is $.modal exactly?

Comment: It's a function to open a modal dialog box. This was created by a team member. @Felix - I think you have the answer for me. Can you add this so I can accept it.

Comment: I created a better example. Take a look ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the modal (var modal = $.modal...) and define this ahead of the two functions.

```
var modal = $.modal

function btnsModal()

function openModal()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can get what you want:

```
function createModal(options) {

    // create your modal and use the options passed
    // like options.message, and options.title for example
    // here you will set its default behavior

}

// calling it
createModal({
    message: "This is the message".
    title: "A modal"
});
```

Here is an example with jQuery UI that you can easyly change to what you need. I just used jQuery UI to make easier build the example since I dont have your $.modal method.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="btn1" type="button">Open Modal 1</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button">Open Modal 2</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    $(function() {

    $( "#btn1" ).click(function(){
        createModal({
            title: "Title!",
            message: "This is a Dialog!"
        });
    });

    $( "#btn2" ).click(function(){
        createModal({
            title: "Another Title!",
            message: "This is another Dialog!"
        });
    });

    function createModal( options ) {

        var $div = $( "<div></div>" );
        $div.append( $( "<p></p>" ).html( options.message ) );

        $div.dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: options.title,
            buttons: {
                "Foo": function() {
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "Bar": function() {
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function( event, ui ) {
                // as the container was created on-the-fly
                // we need to do this to destroy the container
                $(this).dialog( "destroy" );
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/ZJzky/

Answer (score 0):

you need to declair de variable "modal" outside the functions scope to be accessible in both functions.

```
var modal;
function btnsModal() {
    var btns = {
        'Close': function (win) {
            modal.closeModal()
        }
    }
    return btns;
}

function openModal(oLink, content) {
    var btn = btnsModal();
    modal = $.modal({
        buttons: btn
    });
}
```